# Android Animation With OpenGl

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es

I created an animation using AnimationDrawable with less than ten images.
But i got out of memory exceptions when the number of images becomes 50 or 100. Is there any way to do this by using OpenGl .I ask this question since i don't use opengl.Help me to find way to do this .

Comment: Are you sure that animation cannot be done with an xml animation or at least less frames?

Comment: I created xml animation.But If load large number of images,Which is used for animation,OOM happens

Comment: Have you looked into using a canvas? You could then draw your images in one by one, instead having to load them all at once with the drawable.